# mouseenter event on background svg elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, snap.svg

Is there a way of triggering `mouseenter` events on SVG elements that are behind other elements? It seems like the top element is catching the event and it is not bubbling up the DOM.

Alternatively, is there a good way of checking if the mouse is over a specific SVG element?

To clarify, I am trying to implement a 'drag & drop'-like functionality where i change the front element depending on the back one. Note that the elements are not nested.

Comment: Some demo would be very helpful. It seems you should listen for mousemove of a parent element and emualate mouseenter manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the answer. The trick is to set `pointer-events: none` for the element when you start the drag (on `mousedown`) and then back to `pointer-events: all` when you finish dragging. That way the element doesn't capture any of the events, and lets them pass through to whatever is in the background.